# Extract record from bigquery table and store it as a python variable in airflow dag

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

I have a bigquery table which always has only one record. I need to fetch the record and store it as a python variable.

schema of bigquery table:
filename
b
filename is the column name and 'b' is the record within. b is a string.
I want a python variable (suppose 'p') and this should have p=b.
Please help me with the airflow dag.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It's helpful to include any code you already have if you've made a start

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I do not have your DAG code, I will share how to fetch the data from your BigQuery table and store it in a variable using the Python API.

Following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python), make sure you have the client library installed within your instance. I have used a public dataset and dummy data for demonstration purposes. The following code uses the Client library to create a BigQuery client and perform two queries. Then from the query results, since it is just one value for each query, the data is store in two different variables. Below is the code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas

client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = client.dataset("stackoverflow", project="bigquery-public-data")
dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_ref)

#Query result is an INT64
query_1 = """
                SELECT COUNT(a.id) as count
                FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` AS a
                """
#Query result is a STRING
query_2 = """SELECT "Jack Sparrow" as name """

res_1 = client.query(query_1) 
res_2 = client.query(query_2) 

#storing the query result(int64) in a variable
for row in res_1:
    var_1 = row.count

#storing the query result(string) in a variable    
for row in res_2:
    var_2 = row.name
    
print("Checking the var_1: {} . Now checking var_2: {}".format(var_1,var_2))
```

And the output,

```
Checking the var_1: 29468374 . Now checking var_2: Jack Sparrow
```

Notice that ***var_1*** and ***var_2*** were accessed outside as simple variables in Python, one being an INTEGER and the other STRING. Therefore, you can increment this piece of code (with your own query) in your DAG. I want to stress that you need to check [python_operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html) in order to implement it, also [this](https://gist.github.com/skozz/20c8166c45bcc3bcaeb1f7c1144658b0) is a good example.